# set text in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn c#

Tags: c#

I want to set a text in a specific cell in my data grid view. i populate the grid view with DataGridViewTextBoxColumns. Can somebody help?

here i set up the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

```
private void setUpGridTableForGridView(int rows, int columns)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < columns;i++ )
                {
                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns.Add(dgc);
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < rows;i++ )
                {
                    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows.Add();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access to any cell of grid by index of row and column:

```
int row = 0; 
int column = 0;
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView[column, row].Value = "hello world";
// or
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value = "hello world";
```

also you can add rows with values:

```
for (int i = 1; i < rows;i++ )
{
     RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows.Add(string.Format("row{0} column 0", i), string.Format("row{0} column 1", i));
}
```

Comment: thx it helped :), do you know how i can change the "Hello world" to be bigger or have another text style

Comment: use RunTimeCreatedDataGridView[column, row].Style.Font property; if you need to change setting for the column, use RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[column].DefaultCellStyle.Font

Comment: im getting an error of - only assingment, call. in my code i have this RunTimeCreatedDataGridView[column, row].Style.Font.Bold;

Comment: create new Font object and set it to property : RunTimeCreatedDataGridView[column, row].Style.Font = new Font(...)